# Is there any way to genarate a string which will have index wise alternative cases?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I was attempting a problem which stated:
"Define a function called myfunc that takes in a string, and returns a matching string where every even letter is uppercase, and every odd letter is lowercase. Assume that the incoming string only contains letters, and don't worry about numbers, spaces, and punctuation. The output string can start with either uppercase or lowercase letter, so as long as letters alternate throughout the string."
So, I tried the following block of code:

```
def myfunc(word):
    i = 0
    while i!=len(word):
        if (i+1)%2 == 0:
            word[i] = word[i].upper()
        i+=1
    return word
```

But python interpreter threw an error, which stated:

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

So what should be the solution of this problem?

Comment: `''.join([''.join(t) for t in zip(s[0::2].lower(),s[1::2].upper())])` where `s` is your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are not lists, and you can't assign characters to indices. That's because strings are immutable — once created, you can never change them. You might think that you can, but whenever you do, you are instead creating a new string and assigning it to the same name.

As for your problem, one solution would be to create a list in which you store the characters you want your new string to consist of, and then creating a new string from it at the end:

```
def myfunc(word):
    chars = []  # an empty list
    for index, char in enumerate(word):  # this makes the whole indexing thing easier
        if index % 2 == 0:
            chars.append(char.lower())
        else:
            chars.append(char.upper())
    return "".join(chars)
```

Note that I change the case in *both* cases, because, according to the problem statement, the incoming string could be all-caps already.

You could also create new strings instead of using a list (i.e. define `chars` as an empty string and do e.g. `chars += char.lower()`), but that will create many strings of different sizes before finally returning the full string — it would work, though, just not be as efficient. If efficiency is what you're after though, try this version:

```
def myfunc(word):
    return "".join(
        char.upper() if index % 2 else char.lower()
        for index, char in enumerate(word)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option in addition to the answers provided:

```
from itertools import cycle

def myfunc(word):
    funcs = cycle((str.lower, str.upper))
    return ''.join(next(funcs)(char) for char in word)
```

Example:

```
import string
print(myfunc(string.ascii_lowercase))
```

Output:

```
'aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable and don't support an item assignment. Try convert str to list or bytearray or smth else mutable, apply operation and transform it back into str.

```
def myfunc(word):
    array = [c for c in word]  # inefficient, but wotks
    while i!=len(word):
        if (i+1)%2 == 0:
            array[i] = array[i].upper()
        i+=1
    return "".join(array)  # convert list into string
```